# Pandas/Altair - plot multiple series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization, altair

I have the following Pandas DataFrame (from `read_csv`):

```
In [6]: rev_df.head()
Out[6]:
          Entity Code  Year  National Gov Revenues (Wallis (2000))  Local Gov Revenues (Wallis (2000))  State Gov Revenues (Wallis (2000))
0  United States  USA  1902                                    3.0                                 4.0                                 0.8
1  United States  USA  1913                                    2.4                                 4.2                                 0.9
2  United States  USA  1922                                    5.8                                 5.2                                 1.7
3  United States  USA  1927                                    4.7                                 6.0                                 2.1
4  United States  USA  1934                                    6.0                                 7.6                                 3.8
```

`Year` is a column, and there are 3 additional columns, 1 each for Local/State/National revenues. I'd like to create a stacked area chart, like this:
[https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/government-revenues-national-income?country=~USA](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/government-revenues-national-income?country=%7EUSA)

My altair code should hopefully look like this:

```
alt.Chart(rev_df).mark_area().encode(
  x = 'Year',
  y = 'Revenue',
  color = 'Level' ## where level is {Local|State|National}
)
```

I'm having trouble understanding the best transforms to apply on my DataFrame to do this cleanly and comprehensibly. What's the best approach? I think I need to create a single column, `Level`, and essentially triple the number of rows in the DataFrame, but I'm not sure how to articulate or implement this transform.

Related - I've been transforming the `Year` column, which is `int64` as returned by `read_csv`, thus:
`rev_df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(rev_df['Year'], format='%Y')`

Is there a best practice here? Or is this fine?

Comment: i can do this in matplotlib.  is there a reason that you specify Altair ?

Comment: Yes, the point is I'm trying to learn altair. Actually the desired altair syntax above is really expressive and I like it, you're just adding a `color`. I think my problem is lack of fluency with pandas.

Comment: for reference something like this: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_stacked_area_chart.html

Comment: can you provide the dict or the dataframe, so that users can copy / paste the data.  thanks.

Comment: You can go to this link: https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/government-revenues-national-income?country=~USA and click on "download" to retrieve a CSV.

Comment: The data is wide, while altair expects long form data, see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html. You can fold the 3 columns as in https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_with_loess.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform_fold` as mentioned in the comment from debbes:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


rev_df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(
'''
Entity        Code Year  National  Local  State
UnitedStates  USA  1902  3.0       4.0    0.8
UnitedStates  USA  1913  2.4       4.2    0.9
UnitedStates  USA  1922  5.8       5.2    1.7
UnitedStates  USA  1927  4.7       6.0    2.1
UnitedStates  USA  1934  6.0       7.6    3.8
'''
    ),
    sep='\s+',
    parse_dates=['Year']
)

alt.Chart(rev_df).mark_area().encode(
  x = 'Year',
  y = alt.Y('Revenue:Q', stack=True),
  color = 'Level:N'
).transform_fold(
    ['National', 'Local', 'State'],
    as_=['Level', 'Revenue']
)
```

[image]

Your date approach is fine but you can also use `parse_dates` as in my example above.