# chart objects not showing on the chart using selection containing fields with converted columns from datetime data

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, altair, vega-lite

I am using Altair to create visualisations based on a local csv file about WW1 bombing incidents.nI tried to make 2 charts: one shows all incidents in the same month, one shows all incidents in the same year.

The new columns are in int64:

```
# the head of the dataset
 month  year  
   10  1917  
   10  1917  
   10  1917  
   10  1917  
   10  1917
```

```
df_filtered.loc[:, 'month'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['MSNDATE'], format='%M').dt.month.astype(int)
df_filtered.loc[:, 'year'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['MSNDATE'], format='%Y').dt.year.astype(int)

year_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['year'], nearest=True, on='click')
month_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['month'], nearest=True, on='click')

# For the same year
same_year_incidents = alt.Chart(df_filtered, title='Incidents in the same year').mark_circle(opacity=op_var).encode(
alt.X('WEAPONWEIGHT', axis=alt.Axis(title='Weapon weight')),
alt.Y('BOMBLOAD', axis=alt.Axis(title='Bombload'), scale=alt.Scale(nice=10, zero=False, padding=1)),  
color = attackercolor,
size = alt.value(150),
tooltip = ["COUNTRY", "TGTCOUNTRY", 'MSNDATE:T', 'WEAPONWEIGHT', 'BOMBLOAD']
).transform_filter(
year_selection
).add_params(
op_var, brush
).interactive().properties(height=200, width=650)

# For the same month
same_month_incidents = alt.Chart(df_filtered, title='Incidents in the same month').mark_circle(opacity=op_var).encode(
alt.X('WEAPONWEIGHT', axis=alt.Axis(title='Weapon weight')),
alt.Y('BOMBLOAD', axis=alt.Axis(title='Bombload'), scale=alt.Scale(nice=10, zero=False, padding=1)),  
color = attackercolor,
size = alt.value(150),
tooltip = ["COUNTRY", "TGTCOUNTRY", 'MSNDATE:T', 'WEAPONWEIGHT', 'BOMBLOAD']
).transform_filter(
month_selection
).add_params(
op_var, brush
).properties(height=200, width=650)
```

The charts are shown properly when I run the code block:
[Charts before selecting any object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU1qT.png)

However, when I click on an chart object(here the top object on the date 14/9/1918) in the bombing_over_time chart, the 2 new charts do not show any object.
[image: clicking on a chart object with MSNDATE = 14/9/1918]
[image: no object shown]

I do not understand why it does not work since the columns used for the year_selection and month_selection are just in the type of int64. How can I fix it? I am new to coding and I have never coded in python before. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for carefully going through the steps of what you have done. Could you break this down to an as small example as possible and post it with the data? That would make it easier for others to help, see [mre]. For example, no need to include the data wrangling, just a snippet of data as text and then two charts: one where you click and one that should update (this can also help you isolate the issue).

Comment: @joelostblom Thank you for your response. I have tried to make it more concise. Please do inform me if you need more detail on this.

Comment: Thanks for updating the example. Let me clarify what I meant: the goal when creating a question is that people reading it can understand it quickly and also copy/paste the code to reproduce the error on their machines. Then troubleshooting will be easier. You can see an example of what I mean here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73408883/pandas-altair-plot-multiple-series/73412548#73412548.

Could include the first few rows of the data containing all the columns and code needed to create the chart titled "Number of bombings" and the one with "Incidents in the same month"